# How to prove that $3\mid f_k\iff k=4n$ by contradiction.

Tags: induction

> You should formed the conjecture that $3\mid f_k$ if, and only if,
> $k=4n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$.
>
> $(a).$ Prove that for any $k>4,f_k=3f_{k-3}+2f_{k-4}$.
>
> $(b).$ Use this formula and an induction argument to prove that $3\mid f_{4n}$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$.
>
> $(c).$ Use this formula and a proof by contradiction to show that if $3\mid f_k$, then $k=4n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

I was able to figure out part $(a)$ and $(b)$ but I am stuck on part $(c)$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what you did for (b).

Comment: Please, have the courtesy of write the problem, don't just paste a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Deduce from the formula that $3|f_k$ implies $3|f_{k-4}$ as well.

Now suppose the statement does not hold so that $\{n\mid n \neq 0 \pmod{4} \land 3|f_n\}$ is non-empty. Consider its minimum in light of the first statement.